# fn+pgup (home) button key in Fujitsu Lifebook PH521 is not working on Ubuntu 14.04-01

Tags: 14.04, xorg, keyboard

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 64bit on my 2 years old laptop (Fujitsu Lifebook PH521) it is an AMD E-450 powered laptop.

Everything is working right, except the "home" (fn+pgup) and "end" (fn+pgdn) button on the keyboard that is half working.

Right after logging in to desktop (unity), it only works **ONCE** for both keys.

For Example: I opened up a terminal with (Ctrl-Alt-t) then type something on the prompt. And then hit fn+pgup (home) and the cursor would jump to the beginning of the line. Then I hit fn+pgdn (end) and the cursor would jump to the end of the line.
After that, I hit fn+pgup (home) again, and the cursor would not move anymore.

After spending 2 days googling and scouring the forums, I've tried these before asking this question on askubuntu.com:

1. run `xev` and the fn+pgup, fn+pgdn doesn't produce any event.
2. run `showkey` as root, and the fn+pgup would produce press event with 102 code, but no release event. the fn+pgdown would produce press event with code 107, and no release event as well.
3. Hit `Ctrl-Alt+F1` to open non-X console to test the key, and both fn+pgup and fn+pgdn works flawlessly there.
4. Add hwdb.d config (`fujitsu-keyboard.hwdb`) to synthesize the release event for the fn+pgup and fn+pgdn in /etc/udev/hwdb.d/ with this content:

   ```
   # Lifebook PH521
   keyboard:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnFUJITSU*:pn*LIFEBOOK*PH521*:pvr*
   KEYBOARD_KEY_66=!home
   KEYBOARD_KEY_6b=!end
   ```

   then run `udevadm hwdb --update` as root and rebooted.

Other fn+key combination works fine such as volume up/down, brightness up/down so this is really weird. If anyone can help me, I'd really appreciate it.

Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Belated answer, I know, but I thought it's worth posting as I've been having the same issue with a Dell Inspiron laptop and Ubuntu 16.04 and spent over a week on and off trying to resolve it. Have a look at the thread below, adding the correct key codes to the `/sys/bus/serio/devices/serio0/force_release` file resolved my issue. I didn't have the following file `/usr/lib/udev/keymap`  on my system, but was able to find the codes using keytouch-editor.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1279232#p1279232

Airman